# How to get back 1st string after call addslashes() function in PHP

Tags: php

I assign  String(`Con\\ec't`) in to the `$user_val` as look below

```
$user_val = addslashes(Con\\ec't);
```

Next I want to write `$user_val` into another PHP file as a Global constant. After that that string with slashes assign `NAME` constant

```
define ( 'NAME', 'Con\\\\ec\'t' );
```

I tried to get first string using code below

```
 $mystring = stripslashes(NAME);
```

That gave me `Con\ec't` but I want to get `Con\\ec't` for `$mystring`. If you know please help me.

Comment: Are you sure that `Con\\\\ec\'t` is what actually goes to constant? How exactly do you define it? I mean what will happen if you `var_dump(NAME)`.

Comment: Off topic, but I'd be interested to know what you're using `stripslashes` and `addslashes` for -- for most cases where they might be used, they're the wrong choice of function. If you're using them at all, there's a strong chance that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: what i want is define NAME as Con\\ec't, so i first try `define(name 'Con\\ec't');` but this php syntax error. After that i use add addslashes(). when i use addslashes() `Con\\ec't` become `Con\\\\ec\'t` this ok with php syntax. Now i want to get print `Con\\ec't` from `Con\\\\ec\'t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not perfect but this work for me.

```
 $user_val = base64_encode(Con\\ec't);
```

and define as

```
define ( 'NAME', base64_decode('aHR0cDovL3NheHdWIvc2VhcmNo'));
```

output is same as user enter value is(`Con\\ec't`) Please is there any disadvantages with this solution please explain

Comment: Disadvantage: People have to decode base64 to work out what the value is. Seriously bad for readability [and therefore bad for maintainability].

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> define ( 'NAME', 'Con\\\\ec\'t' );
> ```
>
> I try to get 1st sting using below code
>
> ```
> $mystring = stripslashes(NAME);
> ```
>
> that gave to me Con\ec't but i want to get Con\ec't for $mystring

You can’t get `Con\\ec't` *after* strip_slashes, because your constant `NAME` *already* contains the value `Con\\ec't` only.

The four slashes you used in the constant definition result in only **two** slashes, because one `\` escapes the following one.

So, strip_slashes on two backslashes results in, naturally, just one backslash. Absolutely no “magic” going on here.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mystring = preg_replace('/\\+/', '\\', NAME);
```